# Background image in nextjs using stylejsx

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx, next-images

i'm quite confused with NextJS and background property.

in a component, i want to make a hero section but i don't find how to use it in style jsx.

My component :

```js
const homeTitle = () => (
    <div className="home_title">
    <p>My title</p>
    <h1>something else </h1>
    
    <style jsx>{`
    .home_title{
        text-align: center;
        background: url(/public/background.jpg) no-repeat;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    `}</style>
    </div>
);

export default homeTitle;
```

I've tried to install and set next-images, and configure in next.config.js like this :

```
// next.config.js
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages()
```

i also tried to use require in the image url...

how could i use background image in next js ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: `url('${require('../public/background.jpg')}');` does this work? giving path of background image

Comment: I've already tried but it give me a Module not found: Can't resolve '../public/background.jpg' in '/Users/myprofile/Desktop/projectfolder/src/components/HomePage', my image is in the public folder

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : OK i found the way, first, i import image like this:

```
import Hamburger from '../../public/hamburger.svg';
```

then, in my jsx, i use it like this:

```
<style jsx>{`
    .hamburger{
        width: 62px;
        height: 62px;
        background: url(${Hamburger}) no-repeat;
    }
  `}</style>
```